# programmatically check for subsystem

Tags: c++, windows

I have a .exe created with a windows subsystem.  I copy that .exe to another .exe, and I run:

```
editbin.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE my.exe
```

So my intention is to have a .exe that runs with a GUI, and another .exe that is meant for command line operations (no GUI).

How do I check what subsystem is currently active in my C++ code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subsystem type (GUI, console, etc.) is stored in the PE header, which you can access via the ImageHlp functions.  You can get it with the following code:

```
// Retrieve the header for the exe.  GetModuleHandle(NULL) returns base address
// of exe.
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS header = ImageNtHeader((PVOID)GetModuleHandle(NULL));
if (header->OptionalHeader.Subsystem == IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI)
{
    // Console application.
}
```

Relevent MSDN entries:

[ImageNtHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680212(VS.85).aspx)
[IMAGE_NT_HEADERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680336(VS.85).aspx)
[IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680339(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [ImageLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680209(VS.85).aspx) function in the Imagehlp library. This returns a [LOADED_IMAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680349(VS.85).aspx) structure which has a [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680336(VS.85).aspx) structure in its FileHeader field. The OptionalHeader field in this structure is an [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680339(VS.85).aspx) which has a Subsytem filed containg the information that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Far easier than spelunking in your own headers: check if you've got console handles.
For a GUI subsystem app, `GetStdHandle()` will return `NULL` handles.